# Change in gnu ld linker behavior

Tags: linux, linker, g++, ld

When I went from using GNU ld version 2.20 to 2.21 , I began seeing the following change in behavior. Not sure if it is broken behavior in 2.20 that was fixed in 2.21 or if something else is going on.

```
libfoo.so : provides symbols foo() 
libfoobar.so : provides symbol bar() and specifies libfoo.so in its DT_NEEDED slot
main.cpp : uses symbols foo() as well as bar()
```

Previously, I could build main.cpp by just doing :

```
g++ main.cpp -lfoobar
```

The internal dependency of foobar.so on foo.so would ensure that foo() as well as bar() are found

Now, the above does not work and I have to explicitly link foo as well :

```
g++ main.cpp -lfoobar -lfoo
```

So my question is : What is the right behavior - If a .so has dependencies, then are they considered when searching for symbols used directly in the executable or are these dependencies available in a private namespace for the .so only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is : What is the right behavior

The new behavior is the right one.

> If a .so has dependencies, then are they considered when searching for symbols used directly in the executable

No. Whatever dependencies `libfoobar.so` has is a *private* implementation detail, that can change tomorrow. You should *not* count on it. If you use symbols from `libfoo.so`, then you *should* specify `-lfoo` on command line.